# Exercise 115; should I use getters/setters or something else?

Tags: class, object, setter, getter, public-method

I took care of exercise 105. I don't know what to do with 115 though. I've worked a little bit more and progressed a slight bit, but here's the exercise:

A team of biologists is conducting an experiment that involves collecting data on animals founds in a 1 km square area of woodland. As each animal is identified, a record is made of its name, the time of its discovery, and the initials of the scientist who found it. The data are to be recorded on a laptop. Design and implement a system for storing the data, and test your code thoroughly.

[Hint: Think in terms of creating an object for each discovery. What information should each object store, and in what will you store these objects?]

Here is my code:

```
// put class definitions here



public class Record{

    String name;

    String initials;

    String time;



    public Record{

        this.name = name;

        this.initials = initials;

        this.time = time;

    }

}
```

Here's another section for me to test my solution in:

```
public static void main( String[] args )

{

  // test your solution here



}
```

So I know I'm supposed to make a new Object out of the variables, but do I need to use getters and setters or something? If that was the case it would probably be a lot easier than I'm assuming.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters is a common pattern for getting internal member variables from Objects. They are not mandatory, but it is a good practice.

You need to read some Java and Object Oriented book to understand why we use it that way. You need to understand why encapsulation is encouraged too.

```
public class Record{

    protected String name;

    protected String initials;

    protected String time;



    public Record{

        this.name = name;

        this.initials = initials;

        this.time = time;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    //... etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't have a perfect answer, but I'll show you some improved code. It still isn't perfect and I don't know where in my subclass to put my arraylist, getters, or setters...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249342/getters-setters-arraylist-dont-know-where-to-place-in-subclass